# How to inserb CLOB data?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why when inserting clob from 1 to 2 table clob column is empty.
I wanted to insert only unique elements 
After error 
**destination buffer too small to hold clob**

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_column,1, 12000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you were trying to get the substring starting at position 1 and of length at most 12000, right?

For reasons only known to Oracle (and perhaps not even to them), the syntax of the `DBMS_LOB` programs is not consistent with the syntax of their standard string functions.

In `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`, the second argument is the desired length, and the third is the starting position. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66748

So, try `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_column, 12000, 1)`.

With that said - I don't see how trying to copy a CLOB column from one table to another you would get an error like "buffer too small". I don't think you told us your true story. Of course, we can't help you fully if that's the case.